# Internet Proxy settings don't work in terminal. How to configure them?

Tags: command-line, proxy

In our college we access Internet through proxy settings which include address, port, username and password. These settings work well in Firefox but not in terminal for downloading and updating. I have already edited apt.conf file and bash.bashrc accordingly.

apt.conf with

```
Acquire::https::proxy "https://edcguest:edcguest@172.31.102.14:3128/";  
Acquire::http::proxy "http://edcguest:edcguest@172.31.102.14:3128/";  
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://edcguest:edcguest@172.31.102.14:3128/";  
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://edcguest:edcguest@172.31.102.14:3128/";
```

bash.bashrc at the end with

```
export http_proxy="http://edcguest:edcguest@172.31.102.14:3128"  

export ftp_proxy="http://edcguest:edcguest@172.31.102.14:3128"
```

Please explain in detail how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Almost every command line tool which uses the Internet has a proxy option, usually `--proxy`. Consult the manual page of the specific tool for the proxy option. You may also need to specify the proxy type. Which tool do you exactly need to use proxy for?

Comment: try running `env` command and check for `http_proxy` ,`https_proxy`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a python program named UBPROXY . Given below are the steps to set proxy Authentication.

http://code.google.com/p/ubproxy/downloads/detail?name=ubproxy

Download this program. Then open your terminal and run these commands:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

(Presuming that your download exist in this directory)

```
chmod +x ubproxy
sudo ./ubproxy
```